# pip3 install bpy Building wheel for bpy (setup.py) ... error Failed to build bpy

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, blender-2.49

Failed to build bpy. Watch this problem here:

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO52E.png

Comment: Hello! Instead of posting a picture (or a link to another site) please copy the contents of the error into the StackOverflow editor and edit it properly so that the question is of higher quality.

Comment: A quick look at the picture says that you don't have `svn`. You need to install the Subversion binary on your machine.

Comment: Like the comment says, please paste your error into a code block rather than pasting an image.  Images are not searchable and will not help others with the same problem.